# JPA: locking dependent objects (eclipselink)

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, eclipselink

i have a simple one to many relationship in JPA. for the sake of discussion assume my entities are Person and Phone, where a Person can have many Phone (numbers).

both object can be updated independently, and i have high concurrency. i need to implement pessimistic locking on both objects (that's my assumption anyway).

so, in my code, i do something like,

```
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Person p = em.find(Person.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
            ...
```

and similarly for Phone,

```
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Phone ph = em.find(Phone.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
            ...
```

note that in the Person transaction, the dependent Phone object may be updated, and vice versa. the use case is a lastModified flag. updating a Phone updates the lastModified timestamp in the owning Person, and conversely, updating the lastModified timestamp in the Person updates the lastModified flag in the Phone (this is done via entity listeners). i realize the use case is a little contrived, but try to ignore that.

the above code results in dead lock.

```
INFO: [EL Warning]: 2011-06-30 08:41:52.65--ServerSession(122902)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
Error Code: 30000
```

my hypothesis at this time is that the Person transaction grabs a lock for Person A, then is trying to get a lock for Phone 1. at the same time, the Phone transaction grabs a lock for Phone 1, beating the Person transaction, then tries to grab a lock for Person A. deadlock.

this is just a guess, and it's based on a naive understanding of how transactions work, and essentially zero knowledge of how object locking works in JPA. i would *think* that the object and it's dependents are locked atomically ... that's what needs to happen for this to work.

any thoughts?

one idea to fix this, that i'll be trying, is to forget about updating the dependent objects in the same transaction. in stead, open a new transaction after the first finishes to update the dependent object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems very strange to me that you, at the same time

- need pessimistic locks (which seems to imply that you really don't want two transactions to update persons/phones at the same time)
- are ready to sacrifice data coherence by doing a single operation in two separate transactions

Anyway, if you really need to go with pessimistic locks, make sure that the locks are always requested in the same order (person then phone, or phone then person, but not both). This should prevent the kind of deadlock you are faced with.

Comment: i'll try your suggestion. i tried using optimistic locks, which resulted in OptmisitcLockExceptions. i can't find a good pattern on what i'm supposed to do in that case. from a WS, return 500 to the caller? i'd just like things to work for the client, even if there are delays.

Comment: also, it's not clear how to grab the locks in the correct order. for example, when i'm updating Phone, i don't know the person until i query for it. so should i query with a read lock to get that, then start a new transaction, and grab the locks in the right order there?

Comment: and the real question is: what order does JPA grab the locks, and how can i affect that?

Comment: Whatever the solution, if you have several users trying to update the same data at the same time, you will have to deal with exception. Read http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/07/30/jpa-20-concurrency-and-locking and http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html (especially to know how to set a timeout). Also, whatever the solution : evrything should be done inside a single transaction. As the first tutorial shows, you may however read without lock and then lock explicitely, in order to ensure the same order is always used. JPA grabs the lock when you tell it to lock.

Comment: the immediate problems seems to have been the locking order. in stead of locking in em.find(), i lock manually in a well-defined order regardless of whether it is parent or child object.